# How to store Azure Client Secrets in Prod

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I have a Console application right now that's pulling in some API key's from Azure Key Vault. This console app is a service that's going to be run nightly on a local Windows Server instance.

I'm not sure where to store the Azure Client Secret. Right now it's in app settings.json however Microsoft notes that this shouldn't be stored in plain text but I'm at a loss as where I should store it in production.

Comment: Could you please give more details, what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

Check the below steps to create new `client secret` and store/update the values in `Azure Key Vault`.

- In Azure Portal, Navigate to the  `Azure Active Directory` => `App Registrations` .
- If you have already deployed your Console App, then you can find the deployed ap name in the `App Registrations`.
- If you don't find, click on `New App Registration` .

***Create client secret***

- Navigate to your Application from `App registration` =>`Certificates & secrets` => click on `New client secret`.

[image]

[image]

- Copy the Secret ID for later use (need to update this value for `Key Vault` secret value).

***Storing the Client secret in Azure Key Vault***

- Navigate to your `Azure Key Vault`.
- You can update the value of the existing `Key Vault` or create new one and use it.
- Iam creating the new secret.
  Navigate to your `Key Vault` => `Secrets` => click on `Generate /Import`.
- Paste the `Secret ID` from previous step in place of `Secret value`.

[image]

Newly created Secret
[image]

- Copy the `Secret Identifier` from the newly created `secret` (this has to be updated in Azure App Service=> Configuration App Settings).

[image]

- Deploy your `Console App` to Azure App Service.
- Navigate to your `Azure App Service` => `Configuration` => `Application Settings`.
- Add the new Application Settings with the `Secret Identifier` Value.
  [image]

References taken from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/training-services/microsoft-community-training/frequently-asked-questions/generate-new-clientsecret-link-to-key-vault)

Comment: The original question says the console app is running on a local Windows server, but you have assumed it's running in Azure app service.  If the app is not running in Azure, how does it get to the KeyVault to retrieve the client secret?  It needs the secret to log in to Azure surely?